# Get records from table which exact 1 match for column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an agreement detail table where  I have agreementID. Agreement ID can repeat based on other values. How can I fetch only those rows which have only 1 agreementID in it? Following is the query I am using but not returning the result I want.

```
select AGREEMENT_ID  from Agreement_Detail
GROUP BY  AGREEMENT_ID  Having COUNT(*) = 1
```

Am I missing something?

sample Data :

If agreement_ID is 1 the in details table it can be repeated like

```
Agreement_ID    Pid
1               2
1               3
1               4
```

Also, there can be agreement_ID as 2 as follows

```
Agreement_ID    Pid
2               2
```

I want this 2 as my result.

Answer (score 0):

You seems want `not exists` :

```
select ad.*
from Agreement_Detail ad
where not exists (select 1 
                  from Agreement_Detail ad1 
                  where ad1.AGREEMENT_ID = ad.AGREEMENT_ID and ad1.Pid <> ad.Pid
                 );
```

However, you can also use `GROUP  BY` :

```
select AGREEMENT_ID
from Agreement_Detail ad
group by AGREEMENT_ID
having min(pid) = max(pid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
select pid, count(AGREEMENT_ID)
group by pid
having count(AGREEMENT_ID)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code , instead of doing `group by` on AGREEMENT ID, do a `group by` on PID and make your condition as `having count(Agreement Id) >1`

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:
You need to `COUNT` Pid for each AGREEMENT_ID

```
SELECT tab1.*
FROM Agreement_Detail tab1 JOIN 
   (
    select AGREEMENT_ID, count(PID) As PID
    from Agreement_Detail
    GROUP BY  AGREEMENT_ID 
    having count(PID) = 1
   ) tab2 
ON tab1.AGREEMENT_ID = tab2.AGREEMENT_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way:

```
select Agreement_ID, Pid from (
    select Agreement_ID, Pid, count(*) over(partition by Agreement_ID) as cnt from Agreement_Detail
) t
where cnt = 1
```